# Elegantly create map with object fields as key/value from object stream in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have the following class

```
class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public List<String> hobbies;

    Person(String name, int age, List<String> hobbies)
    {this.name = name; this.age = age; this.hobbies = hobbies;}
}
```

How do I create a Map of age to hobbies like `Map<Integer, Set<String>>`?

The Java 8 way I cooked up is:

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> collect8 = persons.stream()
    .collect(
        toMap(
            p -> p.age,
            p -> p.hobbies.stream().collect(toSet()),
            (hobbies1, hobbies2) ->
                Stream.concat(hobbies1.stream(), hobbies2.stream()).collect(toSet())
        )
     );
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this with `Collectors.groupingBy()` perhaps?

As a related question, I find the version without Java streams to be more readable.

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> collect7 = new HashMap<>();

for(Person p: persons) {
    Set<String> hobbies = collect7.getOrDefault(p.age, new HashSet<>());
    hobbies.addAll(p.hobbies);
    collect7.put(p.age, hobbies);
}
```

Should we go with non streams code if it is easier to read; specially when the streamed version, as seen here, has no intermediate streams with transformations of the data but quickly end in a terminal operation?

Comment: Never use streams just because they're fancy - if the imperative version seems easier to read, stick with it! Streams are a tool, and as such they're useful for *some* problems, not all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at similar example from Java 8 Collectors documentation:

```
Map<City, Set<String>> namesByCity
     = people.stream().collect(groupingBy(Person::getCity, TreeMap::new,                                           
           mapping(Person::getLastName, toSet())));
```

You could use the same approach here.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted yourself: the `Stream` solution might not be as readable as your current non-`Stream`-solution. Solving your problem with `groupingBy` might not look as good as you might expect as you want to transform your `List` into a `Set`.

I constructed a solution with `groupingBy`, `mapping` and `reducing`, but that solution is not that easy to read and did even contain an error. You can read more about that in: [Java 8 stream.collect( ... groupingBy ( ... mapping( ... reducing ))) reducing BinaryOperator-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981783/java-8-stream-collect-groupingby-mapping-reducing-reducing-b) I really suggest to look up the answer Holger gave as it also contains a simpler solution using a custom `Collector` and a little Outlook to Java 9's `flatMapping`, which for me comes close to your non-`Stream`-solution.

But another solution using `groupingBy` I came up with and that actually works is the following:

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> yourmap;
yourmap = personList.stream()
                    .flatMap(p -> p.hobbies.stream()
                                           .flatMap(hobby -> Stream.of(new SimpleEntry<>(p.age, hobby)))
                            )
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                             Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toSet())));
```

for that you need the following imports:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

Of course you can take also a `Tuple` or `Pair` or what you like the most.

But then again not better in any ways.

I would stay with your current non-`Stream`-solution. It is more readable and does what it should do.

Comment: You could not use `(strings, strings2) -> {strings.addAll(strings2); return strings;}`  because `addAll()` returns a `boolean`.
You'd have to create a more elaborate lambda which actually returns a `List`.

Comment: Actually that isn't a problem as I returned one of the sets. But I mistakenly treated the operator as if it was a combiner, which it isn't. If you are interested in that problem too you can look up [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981783/java-8-stream-collect-groupingby-mapping-reducing-reducing-b) or jump directly to [Holger's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42982169/6202869), which by the way also contains two good examples for your question.