# Java 8 stream.collect( ... groupingBy ( ... mapping( ... reducing ))) reducing BinaryOperator-usage

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I played around with a solution using `groupingBy`, `mapping` and `reducing` 
to the following question: [Elegantly create map with object fields as key/value from object stream in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967554/elegantly-create-map-with-object-fields-as-key-value-from-object-stream-in-java). Summarized the goal was to get a map with age as key and the hobbies of a person as a `Set`.

One of the solutions I came up with (not nice, but that's not the point) had a strange behaviour.

With the following list as input:

```
List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(
     new Person(/* name */ "A", /* age */ 23, /* hobbies */ asList("a")),
     new Person("BC", 24, asList("b", "c")),
     new Person("D", 23, asList("d")),
     new Person("E", 23, asList("e"))
);
```

and the following solution:

```
Collector<List<String>, ?, Set<String>> listToSetReducer = Collectors.reducing(new HashSet<>(), HashSet::new, (strings, strings2) -> {
  strings.addAll(strings2);
  return strings;
});
Map<Integer, Set<String>> map = personList.stream()
                                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.age, 
                                                                         Collectors.mapping(o -> o.hobbies, listToSetReducer)));
System.out.println("map = " + map);
```

I got:

```
map = {23=[a, b, c, d, e], 24=[a, b, c, d, e]}
```

clearly not what I was expecting. I rather expected this:

```
map = {23=[a, d, e], 24=[b, c]}
```

Now if I just replace the order of `(strings, strings2)` of the binary operator (of the reducing collector) to `(strings2, strings)` I get the expected result. So what did I miss here? 
Did I misinterpret the `reducing`-collector? Or which documentation piece did I miss that makes it obvious that my usage was not working as expected?

Java version is 1.8.0_121 if that matters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Reduction* should never modify the incoming objects. In your case, you are modifying the incoming `HashSet` that is supposed to be the identity value and return it, so all groups will have the same `HashSet` instance as result, containing all values.

What you need is a [*Mutable Reduction*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction), which can be implemented via `Collector.of(…)` like it has been already implemented with the prebuilt collectors `Collectors.toList()`, `Collectors.toSet()`, etc.

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> map = personList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.age,
        Collector.of(HashSet::new, (s,p) -> s.addAll(p.hobbies), (s1,s2) -> {
            s1.addAll(s2);
            return s1;
        })));
```

The reason, we need a custom collector at all, is that Java 8 doesn’t have the `flatMapping` collector, which Java 9 is going to introduce. With that, the solution will look like:

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> map = personList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.age,
        Collectors.flatMapping(p -> p.hobbies.stream(), Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: Interesting.. At first I even tried to find that `flatMapping` in `Collectors` (or to apply `hobbies.stream()` and to work with it). Good to know it is coming. Oh dear, I mixed up the combiner with the operator. So, that was only a coincidence that switching the parameters delivered the right result. Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: Yes, in a sequential context, the reduction function will always be evaluated as `f(previous, next)` whereas `previous` will be the identity value for the first evaluation and the previous result for subsequent evaluations. So `(a,b)->a` will always end up with the identity value, whereas `(a,b)->b` will use the fresh set created by the mapper function. But in a parallel evaluation, both arguments can be the result of a previous partial evaluation and as the partial results can be empty, either argument could be the identity value, so using the second argument is not a reliable fix.